# How to pass hidden values from view1 to view2 on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two views. I view1 have text boxes to enter basic details. once the customer enters basic details and clicks add more details I need to pass the details entered in view1 should pass to the view2 textbox. I treid passing using hidden. But its not passing to next view. any suggestion please.

View1 Controller:

```
    public ActionResult View1()
    {
        return View();
    }

 [HttpPsot]
 public ActionResult View2()
    {
        return ProcessAction();
    }
```

View2 Controller :

```
    public ActionResult View2()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View1 :

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#add").click(function() {View2", "Application")";
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("View1", "Application", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastName)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstName)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
    <div class="col aligncenter">          
        <div class="form-row topMargin">               
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirsttName)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-9 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="button" id="add" name="add" value="add">Add</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" name=new" value="new">view old</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

View2 :

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("View2", "Application", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col aligncenter">          
        <div class="form-row topMargin">               
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirsttName)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
             </div>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.address)
             </div>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.state)
             </div>
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.zip)
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-9 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" value="osubmit">submit</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: can you post your controller?

Comment: added controllers. please check

Answer (score 1):

Ok a few things wrong on this. First off remove the hidden fields on view1, you don't need them as you have them in your `@Html.TextBoxFor` controls.

Secondly, when you post the form of `view1` to the controller it needs to receive view1's `ViewModel`, and pass the values to View2's `ViewModel`

So we need another method in your controller to handle the `POST` event that happens when you click submit on `View1` and takes your forms values...

```
[ValidateAntiforgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult View1(View1ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.Isvalid)//check if valid
    {
        var newModel = new View2ViewModel()
        {
            Email = model.Email,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            FirstName = model.FirstName
        };
        return View("~/The path of view 2", newModel);//go to view 2
    }

    return View(model);//return the first view if it's not valid
}
```

EDIT: Forgot about the `AntiforgeryToken` on the post method!

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, Views and Controllers are tightly coupled in a way that when you correctly design an MVC application, Views don’t directly communicate with Model classes or with other Views: they deal with Controllers only.

That means that your View1 will have to send its data back to a controller, whose job will be to take these data, execute validation logic, modify the model (if needed) and then call the View2 with the processed data it got from View1. How does that happen?

First, you will need a couple ViewModel that wraps all the data you need

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public string MainData;
}

public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public string DetailsData;
}
```

Then we have the controller. Let’s say you have a controller with a simple `View1` method:

```
public View1()
{
    return View()
}
```

This will call your `View1` that shows empty fields for your model

```
@MyApp.Models.ViewModel

@using(Html.BeginForm(“View1”))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MainData)
    // submit 
}
```

This will result in a `POST`call to the `View1` method in your controller. Because of filter attributes, you can specify a second View1 method in the same controller, whose job will process the data sent from View1 and redirect the user to the View2

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult View1(ViewModel model)
{
    repository.Set(model.MainData);
    return RedirectToAction(“View2”);
}
```

Now, just repeat within your View2 calling an HttpPost method where you update the repository with the DetailsData coming from the View2 form